How can I retrieve the avatar and company name to display on a reshared post?
I am able to pull in the post contents including the content that has been reshared, but no matter what I  try I cannot grab the avatar and actor name.
Below is the code that I am currently using, and these are my current scope permissions:
email, openid, profile, r_1st_connections_size, r_ads, r_ads_reporting, r_basicprofile, r_organization_admin, r_organization_social, rw_ads, rw_organization_admin, w_member_social, w_organization_social
<!-- Reshared Company Avatar and Name -->
    <?php
     // Extract the owner ID from the reshared content
     $person_id = substr($post['resharedContent']['owner'], 12); // Extract person ID

     // Make the API call to LinkedIn to fetch the user's profile
     $profile_url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people/($person_id)?projection=    (id,firstName,lastName,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))";
        
     // Use the stored access token for the request
     $access_token = get_option('linkedin_access_token'); // Assuming the token is stored in options
        
     $response = wp_remote_get($profile_url, array(
      'headers' => array(
      'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $access_token,
      'X-RestLi-Protocol-Version' => '2.0.0',  // Required header for LinkedIn API
      ),
     ));

     // Handle API response
     if (is_wp_error($response)) {
      $profile_data = null;
      error_log('LinkedIn API error: ' . $response->get_error_message());  // Log any errors
     } else {
      $profile_data = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($response), true);
      }

     // Initialize default values for the company name and avatar
     $reshared_company_name = 'Name not available';
     $reshared_company_avatar = 'https://your-avatar-url.com/avatar.jpg';  // Default avatar

     // Extract the name and avatar from the response if available
     if ($profile_data) {
      $reshared_company_name = isset($profile_data['firstName']['localized']['en_US']) ? $profile_data['firstName']['localized']['en_US'] . ' ' . $profile_data['lastName']['localized']['en_US'] : 'Name not available';
      $reshared_company_avatar = isset($profile_data['profilePicture']['displayImage~']['elements'][0]['identifiers'][0]['identifier']) ? $profile_data['profilePicture']['displayImage~']['elements'][0]['identifiers'][0]['identifier'] : 'https://your-avatar-url.com/avatar.jpg';
}
?>


What exactly is not working?
